# The help center instructions for deleting comments need updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Under the section "Flagging a comment:" on https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging,

> simply click the “**x**” that appears when you hover the mouse over the comment.

needs changing to:

> simply click the “**Delete**” **link** that appears when you hover the mouse over the comment.

Similarly, other sites on the Network would probably need updating as well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch. Page now reads:

> You can always delete your own comments without flagging for moderator attention: click the “Delete” link that appears when you hover the mouse over the comment (or tab to it using the keyboard).